# help, no gui or desktop after upgrage from 16.04 to 20.04

Tags: gui

I just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, cannot get a desktop or gui, cannot access home directory.

Upon rebooting I entered my password to decrypt my home directory, then I am logged in at the terminal in my home directory. The only thing in my home directory is:

```
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop 
README.txt
.cache
.ecryptfs
.Private
README.txt
```

I am unable to start `xserver`, it resulted in various errors and does not start.

I also cannot update, running `sudo apt update` returns numerous errors:

```
 Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

 Err:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Could not resolve 'us.archive.canonical.com'

 Err:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Inrelease
 Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

 Err:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
 Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

 Err:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
 Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

 
 Then it says:
4 packaged can be upgraded:
 Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored or old ones used instead.
 
 apt list --upgradeable
 Listing... Done

 gnome-session-bin/bionic-updates 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.21
 gnome-session-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 all [upgradable fro: 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.21
 qtchooser/bionic 64-ga1b6736-5 amd64 [upgradable from: 52-gae5eeef-2build1~gcc5.2]
 ubuntu-sesson/bionic-updates 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 all [upgradable from: 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.21
```

I'm not sure how to update those from the terminal yet, or if that's even the next step.  Pretty far out of my knowledge zone here, thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Try `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` in your terminal.

Comment: @skooster Did you check if the internet is working by using `ping` command?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't post my output because it reads the links in the output as links in my post and I can't do that until I have 10 points on the forum or something. Puting in in CODE doesn't seem to work..

Errors show it could not resolve any of the ' us.archive - bionic- release' of anything, output lines like this:

Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

Other errors were like this:
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

The following packages have been kept back:
gnome-sessions-bin gnome-session-common qtchooser ubuntu-session
0 upgraged, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Neet tro get 17.3kb of archives.
After this operation, 100 kb of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/bionic-updates/main amd64 libgles2 amd64 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3
Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com
E: Failed to fetch http:us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libglvnd/libgles2_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Sorry this is a botched description of the output until I can post in in this editor.

[boot screen img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXk7m.gif)
[boot screen img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kcx9.gif)
[boot screen img 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTjOT.gif)